# The eigenvalues of the sum of a diagonal matrix and a nilpotent matrix are the entries of the diagonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L \in [0,1]^{n \times n}$ be a diagonal matrix and $K \in [0,1]^{n \times n}$ be a nilpotent matrix. I want to prove that the eigenvalues the matrix $S = L + K$ are the eigenvalues of the matrix $L$.

I was trying to use the fact that for every nilpotent matrix $K$ there is a permutation matrix $P$ so that the matrix $K1=P^TKP$ is strictly upper triangular and therefore the eigenvalues of $S1=L + K1$ are the eigenvalues of $L$ but I do not know how to prove that the eigenvalues of $S$ are the same with the eigenvalues of $S1$.

Comment: Could you please let me more details why the eigenvalues of $L+K1$ is the same as $L$? i.e, the strictly upper triangular $K1$ does not change the eigenvalue of $L$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>It is because they are conjugate : $S_1 = P^{-1}SP$. So a vector $x$ is an eigenvector for $S$ if and only if $P^{-1}x$ is an eigenvector for $S_1$, and in this case the corresponding eigenvalues are the same.</s>

More generally, the results also holds if $K$ is nilpotent and $L$ only commutes with $K$. Indeed, after a suitable field extension, $K$ and $L$ both are triangularizable and commute. So there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}KP$ and $P^{-1}LP$ are upper triangular. Then the previous argument is still valid.

EDIT : $S$ and $S_1$ need not be conjugate. For example take $L:=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5\end{pmatrix}$, $K:=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $P:=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Then $L+K = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5\end{pmatrix}$ and $L+ P^T KP = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5\end{pmatrix}$. These matrices cannot be conjugate since they have different Jordan reduction.

Comment: What I'm asking is why $S$ and $S1$ are conjugate. I know they are. But why?

Comment: The matrix $L$ is diagonal so $P^{-1}LP=L$.

Comment: I think that the last argument is not true for any invertible matrix $P$. Consider $L=$ [0.5  0;0  0.2] and $P=$ [1  1;0  1]. Then $P^{-1}LP=$[0.5  0.3;0  0.2].

Comment: Oops, of course it is wrong ! I thought "scalar matrix".

Comment: What about this : if $P$ is a permutation matrix (and not any invertible matrix) then $P^{-1}LP$ is still diagonal. In fact, the coefficients are the same than for $L$, but they are permuted (for example, if $P$ represents the transposition $(i,j)$ then $L_{ii}$ and $L_{jj}$ are exchanged and the other coeff remain the same).

Comment: @Catherine56 By the way, how do you show the existence of the permutation matrix $P$ ? I see a proof using Perron-Frobenius's theorem, but is there any simpler argument ?

Comment: Yes! Indeed this way one can prove it by using also the fact that for any permutation matrix $P$ there exists a $k<=n$ so that $P^k=I$ because $S1=L+K1=I^TLI + P^TKP = (P^k)^TLP^k + P^TKP = P^T((P^T)^{k-1}LP^{k-1} + K)P$ and due to the fact that $(P^T)^{k-1}LP^{k-1} + K$ is upper triangular, from similarity we have what we want...

Comment: I think there is. Any nonnegative nilpotent matrix may represents the adjacency of the nodes of a directed acyclic graph. A graph is acyclic iff there exists a topological order of its vertices. By relabeling those vertices from 1 to n gives you a permutation matrix which renders the adjacency matrix strictly upper triangular.